# mvc3 routing priorty/dot parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following route defined:

```
context.MapRoute("routeCreate", "{aval}/anArea/aController/Create/{val.Id}", new { action = "Create", controller = "aController" });
```

Which functions until the following catch-all route is defined:

```
context.MapRoute("catchallCreate", "{aval}/anArea/{controller}/Create/", new { action = "Create"});
```

The route is invoked by:

```
RedirectToAction("Create", new {val.Id});
```

The resultant URL goes to ?Id=1 instead of /1, it doesn't seem to be picking up the "val." part any more.

I am thinking there might be a problem with using {val.Id} as I cannot create a constraint with that parameter syntax.

Update:

Maybe I'm still missing something, with the following routes defined I am still seeing resolution to ?Id=1 instead of /1

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.Routes.Add(
            new Route(
                "{aval}/anArea/aController/Create/{val.Id}",
                new RouteValueDictionary()
                    {
                        { "action", "Create" },
                        { "controller", "aController" },
                        { "val.Id", UrlParameter.Optional }
                    },
                null,
                new RouteValueDictionary() { { "area", "anArea" } },
                new MvcRouteHandler()));
// catchall
context.MapRoute("Create", "{aVal}/anArea/{controller}/Create", new { action = "Create" });
```

Even with Optional removed it doesn't work. The first route only works if the catchall is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The order that the routes are defined [is important](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx). So you need to define `catchallCreate` after `routeCreate`.

The other thing that you might consider is defining val.Id as optional:

```
routes.Add(new Route("{aval}/anArea/aController/Create/{val.Id}",
                     new RouteValueDictionary()
                         {
                             {"action", "Create"},
                             {"controller", "aController"},
                             {"val.Id", UrlParameter.Optional}
                         },
                     new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

Comment: Custom model binding on the action requires the object.id notation in this instance. Is there any way to define "val.Id = UrlParameter.Optional"? I know that syntax is invalid with the dot notation, perhaps there is a way to escape or define a parameter of this format?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation recently and this was the closest thing I could find in all my searches.

My issue was more of a problem resulting from trying to provide a default for my dotted parameter. What worked for me was the following:

```cs
context.MapRoute("routeCreate", 
                 "{aval}/anArea/aController/Create/{val.Id}",
                 new 
                 {
                    action = "Create",
                    controller = "aController"
                 });

var route = (Route)context.Routes["routeCreate"];
route.Defaults.add("val.Id", UrlParameter.Optional);
```

The [other answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12904955/1441014) route creation method did not work for me due to other controllers sharing the same name in other areas.

And yes, this would render the catch-all route unnecessary as recommended by [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12904955/1441014).